# Init RedisJson with Predis module version error

Tags: php, redis, php-7, predis, redisjson

I'm getting this error found in the `constructor` of `RedisJson` from  [mkorkmaz /
redislabs-rejson](https://github.com/mkorkmaz/redislabs-rejson)

Argument 1 passed to Redislabs\Module\RedisJson\RedisJson::setModuleVersion() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\wamp64\www\aizen_themes\vendor\mkorkmaz\redislabs-rejson\src\RedisJson\RedisJson.php

at this line `$this->setModuleVersion($redisClient->rawCommand('MODULE', ['LIST']));`

when I comment, all the logic related to `moduleVersion` everything works fine

this is how i init the RedisJson

```
$redis = new Predis\Client('tcp://myredis-cloud-remote-url:port');
$redis->auth('user','pass');
$redisJson = RedisJson::createWithPredis($redis);
```

anyone have an idea about it  ?

**UPDATE** :
after investigations about the `MODULE`  command it looks like that is only supported by  C binding functionalities, I think that the library of `Predis` cannot execute such command because it's not written in `C` check this link [Redis modules](https://redis.io/topics/modules-intro)

Comment: Are you working with a Redis Enterprise Cloud instance?

Comment: @PieterCailliau Yes

Comment: The support for `COMMAND LIST` was a missing feature in Redis Enterprise Cloud.  However, it's implemented now and will be rolled out shortly

Comment: That's awesome @PieterCailliau, thank you BTW, I create a custom autoloading function to bypass the module check in the lib need to go to prod asp so what ever it's available I will roll back this implementation

Comment: In RedisInsight we do some checks to verify if certain commands are available using the COMMAND command.  But this should be a temporary workaround